# how can i use playwright for web scrapping and make it a api with fastapi in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, fastapi, playwright

An exceptional issue has arisen that I'm seeking assistance with. The problem presents itself in the form of an error, which I've detailed below:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 83, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 762, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 782, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 297, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 77, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 72, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 299, in app
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 294, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 193, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 40, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 56, in run_sync
    return await get_async_backend().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 2134, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 851, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\chatbot-server\app.py", line 83, in website_extract2
    output = run_playwright("https://google.com")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\chatbot-server\app.py", line 58, in run_playwright
    with sync_playwright() as p:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py", line 77, in __enter__
    dispatcher_fiber.switch()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py", line 56, in greenlet_main
    self._loop.run_until_complete(self._connection.run_as_sync())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 684, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 266, in run_as_sync
    await self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 275, in run
    await self._transport.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 135, in connect
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 123, in connect
    self._proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 224, in create_subprocess_exec
    transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1728, in subprocess_exec
    transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 522, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotI
```

The above traceback is the error that I'm currently facing.

The code that I am using is written in Python and utilizes packages such as 'BeautifulSoup' and 'playwright'. The goal of this script is to extract the title from any given website. However, it seems that an issue has arisen during the process.

Please find the code I've been using below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import io
import re


def run_playwright(site):
    data = ""
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)

        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(site)

        page_source = page.title()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")

        for script in soup(["script", "style"]): # remove all javascript and stylesheet code
            script.extract()
        # get text
        text = soup.get_text()
        # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        # break multi-headlines into a line each
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
        # drop blank lines
        data = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

        browser.close()
    return data

@app.get("/api/website-extract2")
def website_extract2():
    output = run_playwright("https://google.com")

    print(output)
    return output
```

As you can see, the purpose of this code is to extract the title from a range of different websites. However, it seems to be encountering an issue that I'm unable to identify or resolve on my own.

If anyone has any potential solutions or suggestions for how I might be able to address this issue, I would be extremely grateful for your assistance.

Comment: The stack trace seems truncated. There should be a line in the trace that includes your code, at the bottom. Also, it's a little odd to use BS with Playwright. Playwright already has an HTML parser that works on the live set, the browser's native HTML parser. Dumping the page to a string and then re-parsing it with BS seems error-prone and roundabout. Is google.com really the site you're scraping? What text are you expecting to get from it? If you just want the title, `page.title()` should give it.